# When generating a new project using Vue CLI, how does the app know to look for main.js when bootstrapping

Tags: vue-cli

When generating a new project using Vue CLI v.4.0.0 everything is bootstrapped nicely with an index.html file, a couple of .vue files, several configuration files and finally a main.js file. But since the HTML-file does not reference main.js I wonder how Vue knows to look for main.js. Is it implicitly understood by Vue or is there a binding somewhere that tells Vue to look for a file named "main.js"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue CLI runs on Webpack.

Webpack requires an entry file.

You can overwrite the entry file by creating a `vue.config.js` file at the root of your project and adding:

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
     entry: {
        main: './src/overwritten-main-file.js'
     }
  }
}
```

See the Vue.js [Configuration Reference](https://cli.vuejs.org/config) for more info